# In Chrome, can I enter Device Mode directly, without DevTools?

Tags: responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome's [Device Mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports?hl=en) is great for testing responsive layout, however, it seems that I can only enter it from the DevTools, unlike in Firefox where Ctrl+Shift+M takes me to responsive preview from the page directly.

Is there a secret shortcut / some extension for Chrome to enter the Device Mode directly?

Comment: Nope, it [doesn't have a key](https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=IDC_DEV_TOOLS_DEVICES&sq=package:chromium&type=cs). Open an issue on https://crbug.com and link it here so that we can star it.

Comment: @wOxxOm Could Chrome extension possibly provide it? Or is there no API for that?

Comment: Opened an issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=652112

Comment: I really hope this will happen someday. I want my boss to be able to use device mode without devtools, and I often want to view several devices at once. The feature request is really 'option to hide devtools panel with device mode open'. It doesn't need to be extracted into an entirely new feature as the issue suggests.

Comment: Still disappointed :-(

Answer (score 3):

When Device Mode is open and focused <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd></kbd> will toggle Device Mode. There is no way to open DM without opening DevTools first. Device Mode is a *part of* DevTools not an independent feature.

Comment: However, if you just want to use the "look" of Device Mode, for example to present something, you could undock dev tools into its own window and hide it.

Comment: How to immediately open the Device Mode with only one keyboard shortcut. So i don't need to open dev tools and then open device toolbar quickly

Answer (score -1):

This extension does what you want. (kinda)

[Viewport Resizer – Responsive Testing Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/viewport-resizer-%E2%80%93-respon/kapnjjcfcncngkadhpmijlkblpibdcgm?hl=en)

It is better than nothing.