# How can I test retina image substition without retina display?

Tags: javascript, retina

## What I have:

I'm using [retina.js](http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/) to substitute larger sized image variants for retina displays.

## What I need:

I need to test that the script is working. My output should read as:

```
someimage@2x.png
```

...instead of...

```
someimage.png
```

## My problem:

I can't find a means of emulating a retina display that will allow me to check the source code.

## What I've tried:

1. [Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17228146/2971649) suggest that I modify Firefox's config however my default value for `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` is set to -1 (not 1). Changing to -2 or 2 does not produce the necessary result.
2. Opera's Device Emulator does not offer me a means of reading the source code.
3. Chrome has a device mode that allows me to change the device pixel density. The default is 2. Changing the value to 1 or 3 does not produce any noticeable effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could write a test variable in to the URL, and alert the image source, and use a retina device or that opera emulator.

Something like yoursite.com/app?alertImage=test

(assuming you're using jquery):

```
if (location.search.indexOf('alertImage') >= 0) {
    alert($('.imageClass').attr('src'));
}
```